# Angular factory: how to use method in object being declared?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am creating a factory for my angular app.
I am asking how to use a method (here `setCurrentUser()`) in the same factory I am declaring:

```
app.factory('User', function ($rootScope) {
  var User = {
    create: function (authUser, username) {
        // ...
        setCurrentUser(username); // <== ERROR
      });
    },
    // ...
    setCurrentUser: function (username) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
    },
    // ...
  };
  return User;
});
```

Using `this.setCurrentUser(username)` gives an undefined error, of course...
Please note I need `setCurrentUser` to be a method of `User` factory, since I have to use it from controllers (I can't define it to be a local function of `User` factory...).

Comment: How about `User.setCurrentUser` ?

Comment: Switch the places of the methods.
You are using a methods before it's defined.

Comment: @aduch: yes, it works, simple and effective (my bad I didn't think about this solution myself... :-().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to use a closure, since by the time at which you call `User.create()` `User` is defined, so you can call `setCurrentUser`.

```
User.setCurrentUser(username);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this deserves a downvote, so that I can improve it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

What you could do instead is use functions as local vars and return the `User` object (your public API) like this:

```
app.factory('User', function ($rootScope) {
  var setCurrentUser = function (username) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = ...
  };

  var create = function(authUser, username) {
    // ...
    setCurrentUser(username); // <== NO ERROR
  };

  return {
    create: create,
    setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser
  };
});
```

Comment: A good solution, more general then the accepted one (which is more elegant, though... :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare setCurrentUser function before create function declaration. If this won't help, you can use this trick:

```
var that = this;
```

and in User object call setCurrentUser as:

```
that.setCurrentUser
```